# How to disable XA in Qpid 6.1.7 resource adapter in wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, qpid, xa

I'm trying to use the Qpid-6.1.7 resource adapter to connect to RabbitMQ.
The Connection will be established but i recieve a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 0_8 version does not provide XA support

Stacktrace:

```
15:36:14,830 ERROR [org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidExceptionHandler] (Thread-66)[,] Unable to reconnect org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidActivationSpec(ra=org.apache.qpid.ra.QpidResourceAdapter@15fef9c0 destination=jboss/exported/queue/mail destinationType=javax.jms.Queue
ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15 connectionPerHandler=false): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 0_8 version does not provide XA support
        at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.createXASession(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:243)
        at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.createXASession(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:326)
        at org.apache.qpid.client.XAConnectionImpl.createXASession(XAConnectionImpl.java:56)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.QpidResourceAdapter.createXASession(QpidResourceAdapter.java:573)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidMessageHandler.setup(QpidMessageHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidMessageHandler.start(QpidMessageHandler.java:273)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidActivation.setup(QpidActivation.java:122)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidExceptionHandler.handleFailure(QpidExceptionHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.qpid.ra.inflow.QpidActivation$SetupActivation.run(QpidActivation.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've set the Qpid-Ra properties to use a LocalTransaction but the server still throws this error.

standalone.xml:

```
<resource-adapters>
    <resource-adapter id="qpid">
        <archive>qpid-ra-6.1.7.rar</archive>
        <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
        <config-property name="TransactionManagerLocatorClass">org.apache.qpid.ra.tm.JBoss7TransactionManagerLocator</config-property>
        <config-property name="TransactionManagerLocatorMethod">getTm</config-property>
        <config-property name="UseLocalTx">true</config-property>
        <config-property name="ConnectionURL">amqp://guest:guest@clientid/?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672?sasl_mechs='PLAIN''</config-property>
        <connection-definitions>
            <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.qpid.ra.QpidRAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="qpid-ra" pool-name="qpid-ra">
                <config-property name="SessionDefaultType">javax.jms.Queue</config-property>
            </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
        <admin-objects>
            <admin-object class-name="org.apache.qpid.ra.admin.QpidQueueImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/queue/mail" use-java-context="true" pool-name="mail">
                <config-property name="DestinationAddress">queue/mail</config-property>
            </admin-object>
        </admin-objects>
    </resource-adapter>
</resource-adapters>
```

As of now i'm confused why the LocalTX properties don't help within this case.